# Auto generate registration code in custom format

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm new in PHP need some help, i want to generate auto registration code like this (e.g: 0001, 0002, ..) form data base if available in database auto plus one in last number  if not start from 0000 it go at 9999 and stop

my sql table as

id | regisCode | title

query is

```
$query = mysql_query("Select * from accounts");
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($result >  0){

$row = mysql_fetch_array ($result);
} else{
$new = 0000;
}

$account = substr('0000', 1);

$faccount = 1+$account;


echo "<h1>". $faccount ."</h1>";
```

sorry for poor english

Comment: why don't you use the auto incremented key from your table?

Comment: You can use the query **select max(SUBSTRING(regisCode from 4))+1 as uniqueid from table_name**. This will give you the next unique id to be used. The value 4 is not constant, it's just the position from where to start calculation so you can change that according to you requirement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(cast(registration_code as decimal)) id FROM accounts ";  
    if($result = mysql_query($query))
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        $count = $row['id'];
        $count = $count+1;

        $code_no = str_pad($count, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
```

This will generate 0000,0001,0002...wen it will reach to 0099 it will generate 0100..